# 404 on websocket endpoint when Jersey ServletContainer is on "/*"

Tags: rest, websocket, jersey, wildfly, jersey-2.0

I have a JavaEE app running with jersey (2.30) on wildfly. The app has two rest applications on "/rest1" and "/rest2" and a websocket on "/somews".
I needed to merge the two rest applications into one, so I had to define "/*" as the application path. I was able to serve the static resources using the staticContentRegex parameter, but if I try to connect to the websocket I get a 404 error.
It looks like the jersey servlet is interfering with the websocket endpoint, but why is that? they are on different protocols, so I assumed it wouldn't be a problem.

Marco.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone encounters the same problem: I had a custom *ExceptionMapper* that, for a *NotFoundException*, was always returning a response with an entity.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).